# Cloud Firestore: add OR update an array

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating an app where users can upload photos and tag them, and then tags that they have uses are added to the list of that user's interests.
I am making a transition from Realtime database to cloud firestore and having a bit of an issue.

I want to store all these tags in an array inside a document for each user. Whenever a user uploads a photo, these tags should be added to this array.

I am using the `update` method as I don't want the list to be overwritten, but the data doesn't seem to be created at all. Could it be because for a new user the list doesn't actually exist?
I need the function to create the document and array if it is the first time the user adds any interests, or just update the list and add items if the array already exists.

Also, the tags are added to a complete list of all the tags across the app. For this one I've tried to use the `set` method but then the list just gets completely overwritten, even when I added `SetOptions.merge()`

```
val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

val userInterestsDoc = db.collection("interests").document(currentUser.uid)
val allTagsListDoc = db.collection("all_tags").document("all_tags")

for (tag in imageTagsList) {
 userInterestsDoc.update("interests_list", FieldValue.arrayUnion(tag))
                       .addOnSuccessListener {
                        allTagsListDoc.set(
                            mapOf(
                                "all_tags_list" to arrayListOf(tag)
                            ), SetOptions.merge()
                        )
            }
```

Comment: Why are you updating and setting a new value in the same time?

Comment: I'm not. There are two things happening in the code I've attached. One is set and one is update, but they are for different documents. Unfortunately neither does what I need it to.

Comment: Please add a screenshot of your database.

Comment: It's currently empty. That's my problem. It needs to be populated as the user's add content with tags, but these either work just to set up the data and then overwrite it (when using `set`), or only works for updating and doesn't actually creates a new document if it doesn't exist. I might have found a work around for my purpose, but this is still something I wonder about as I am new to cloud Firestore and I can see myself needing to have a function as this.

Comment: In order to be able to update a document, you need to first create it.